# Usage of @Named and @Singleton in Google Guice framework

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

I am new to Guice framework. Have a few basic doubts.

Does adding `@Singleton` annotation ensure that we will get single instance that can be injected as a dependency?
Follow-up: In which case is it necessary to also create a binding explicitly (except when there are multiple implementations to an Interface, this is an obvious scenario)?

Also, I've seen many classes are annotated with `@Named` (from javax.inject) instead of `@Singleton`. When is this exactly required?

So, what if a class which will act as a bean in a Guice application is annotated with both `@Singleton` and `@Named` at the same time?

Answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Annotating with `@Singleton` does exactly what you expect. It tell Guice to only create a single instance of this class.

Explicit bindings are required if you want to bind a class to a super class or an interface.

`@Named` allows to qualify a binding with a name (i.e. a string).
You can also qualify bindings with an annotation.
Qualifying of bindings is required if multiple bindings for a single class/interface exist.

If you combine `@Singleton` and `@Named` than the class will be both, a singleton and a qualified binding.

Note: you can also make a binding singleton, qualified and similar when defining it in a module.